# How to replace ' from the select query

Tags: sql-server-2008, replace, adventureworks

In SQL Server, I have this query

```
SELECT DISTINCT  City FROM 
Person.Address
```

But this gives me two cities which has name like Ville De'anjou (i.e. **'**)

you can try the same by this

```
SELECT DISTINCT  City FROM 
Person.Address
WHERE City like '%''%'
```

Now, I am creating a SSIS package which is creating folder for each city. But the package fails at these two cities and throw this error

```
[ADO NET Source [1]] Error: An error occurred executing the provided SQL command: "SELECT AddressID, AddressLine1,PostalCode, City
 FROM Person.Address WITH(NOLOCK)
 WHERE City = 'Ville De'anjou'". Incorrect syntax near 'anjou'.
Unclosed quotation mark after the character string ' SET FMTONLY OFF;'.
```

It fails because this isn't a correct query.

I have tried with this but no luck, instead it removed those two cities from the list

```
SELECT DISTINCT CITY FROM Person.Address
WHERE City like REPLACE(City,'''', '''''')
```

How can I rectify this error?

Comment: So you're [creating a query by concatenation](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=bobby+tables)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about:

```
SELECT DISTINCT REPLACE(City,'''', '''''') FROM Person.Address
WHERE City like '%''%'
```

Comment: that works when I hard coded the city name. but i want that to be replaced at the time of select only. I.e. **SELECT DISTINCT  City FROM 
Person.Address**